# Visual Basic 6 tutorials for data access and CRUD

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, crud, data-access

Do you know some tutorials (preferably a website or a blog) in Visual Basic 6 (not Visual Basic .NET) for data access or CRUD?  The caliber and depth that I'm looking for is similar to this site:

Data Access Tutorials for ASP.NET

http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/

Although the above site is for web applications, I am looking for a WinForm VB6 tutorial.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You're not writing new code in VB6, are you?

Comment: Please please _please_ don't write new code in VB6.  Express editions of visual studio are freely available for .Net development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has quite a bit.  It's nowhere near as nice as the ASP.NET video tutorials, but it's not bad.

Scroll down for data tutorials.

http://www.vbtutor.net/vbtutor.html